# How do I redirect a user when he is logged in after clicking on a menu

Tags: redirect, login, user-registration

I would like to redirect my logged in users automatically to a next page if they press a button on my menu. I would like to make it that if you're not logged in you'll get on a registration page and when you're logged in you'll get on the correct page (which is a gravity form).

How can I do this?

[image]

I want them to get redirected when they click on the "plaats een opdracht" page. If not logged in they'll be redirected to a registration page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use login redirect filter [login_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) to redirect to the page you want to redirect.

Or you can use [if menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/) plugin to add the conditional menu on login and logout having the same name.

Comment: I don't know any coding but to clarify myself; when a user is logged in and they click on the "plaats een opdracht" button I want them to automatically get redirected to my form. IF the user is not logged in I would like to redirect them to a page where they can login or register before going to the form. Could you please give me the exact code and where I have to put it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (if you are using default WP login/registration) would be adding a link to wp-login.php with the query string parameter "redirect_to" pointing to the URL where logged in users should be redirected.

Comment: If they're already logged in this will still take them to the login page, not straight through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your form page is already protected. Just in case it's not, you can use this code to protect your page from 'non-logged in users'. Place both snippets in functions.php.

```
function sd_protect_pages() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // do nothing because user is already logged in
    } else {
        if ( is_page( 'page-with-your-form' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( 'url-where-to-direct-to' );
            exit;
        }
    }
add_action( 'init', 'sd_protect_pages' );
```

If you place this in your functions.php, a user who visits 'page-with-your-form' gets redirected back to this page (after loggin in).

```
function sd_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    if ( false != $user ) {
        if ( 'page-with-your-form' == $request ) { 
            $redirect_to = 'page-with-your-form';
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;

}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'sd_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

I think this would do the trick.

Comment: Alright and instead of the 'page-with-your-form' i just put the URL of that certain page in? or what

Comment: Partially yes. You replace 'page-with-your-form' with the full URL in the $redirect_to line. The line with == $request should only have the slug of the page which contains the form. I see you're Dutch (like me). If you need help with WP in the future, I'm a freelancer, you can always hit me up through my website (see my profile).